# Simple ways of synchronizing offline data with an online datastore using html5?

Tags: html, synchronization

What are some very simple ways for me to make an html5 app that syncs whatever changes the user makes while offline to the server?

For example, let's say there is a wiki at somewiki.com. I visit somewiki.com on my ipad. It's a small wiki, so my ipad downloads the entire datastore to its local html5 storage. I go offline and use the wiki html5 app as usual, as if I were online, making edits to pages. Then I return online, and the changes I made are synchronized with the online datastore.

Of course a lot of parts of this problem require some design decisions (for example, how to integrate my offline page edits if another user has edited the page while I was offline), but please point to the simplest general proof-of-concept for this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the HTML `ononline` event.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: That helps a lot. Hopefully someone will post a javascript library that does more of this functionality automagically for a particular type of datastore (for example, mongodb).